# Handle exception regarding its message from getMessage()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

Is it good practice to handle an exception regarding its message from getMessage() on Android platform?

In my android app, I have for example following class:

```
public class Test {

    boolean alreadyTried;

    public Test() {
        alreadyTried = false;
    }

    private void doTest() {

        try {
            downloadPictureFromServer(); //uses okhttp3

        } catch (Exception e) {

            if(e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().contains("Connection reset by peer")){
                //try again (only once)
                if(alreadyTried) {
                    Log.e("Test", "Connection reset by peer repeatedly, cannot communicate with the server");
                } else {
                    Log.e("Test", "Connection reset by peer, trying to communicate with the server again...");
                    alreadyTried = true;
                    doTest(); //try again
                }
                
            } else {
                throw e;
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When *doTest()* is called it starts communicating with web app running on Tomcat server,  sometimes following exception is thrown:

*javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7653281108: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer*

It is very unlikely to happen, but it can happen when the server is being restarted... etc. It already happened to me during testing more than once.

So, can I use the message and safely check if it contains "**Connection reset by peer**" string? Or is there a chance the message from getMessage() will be in different language than English?

I tried to look for this info, but I couldn't find anywhere... I want to be sure it is OK to handle it like in this example and calm my mind. I also tried to change the language in my android device to German or Czech and the exception message was still in English, so that is a good sign.

**Update:**
Regarding *Stephen C* answer I changed the if condition to:

```
if(e instanceof SSLHandshakeException) {
//try again (only once)
...
}
```

This is not so specific regarding the exception, but it is more safe to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is generally not a good idea for a program to try to unpick the message string in an exception.

Problems:

- Exception strings can be internationalized<sup>1</sup>. The correct way to do it is to override `Throwable.getLocalizedMessage`, but it is also possible to internationalize the primary exception message; e.g. before constructing the exception.  The latter could present problems for message parsing.
- Exception strings may change from one Java(tm) or Android platform version to the next.  Generally speaking, this is not considered a significant enough change to be noted in release notes, etcetera.  So code that parses exception messages is *liable* to be fragile.

A better idea is to design the exception hierarchy so that you don't need to parse the messages:

- Add exception subclasses for cases that handlers need to distinguish.
- Define custom exception fields to hold values that handlers might otherwise have to extract.

Another approach is to avoid the *temptation* to do fancy things.  (In your example, do you *really* need to handle resets differently?)

But obviously, when the circumstances demand it, you may have to parse the messages anyway, despite the potential problems.

---

<sup>1 - There are different "schools of thought" on whether it is a good idea or not.</sup>